# Extracting number from string using lua

Tags: lua, numbers, pattern-matching, detection, extract

I have the following string as an input:

"totalling  7,525.07"

In the code below the string is indicated as "a.message"

```
print (string.match(a.message, "(%d+),(%d+)(%d+)(%d+).(%d+)") )

sum = (string.match(a.message, ".-(%d+). -([%d%.%,]+)") )
```

The code above only produces a number 7 rather than the whole number.  Ideally I'm after the whole number but my code is stripping out the decimal from the figure.  I've tried all sorts of different configurations but don't seem to getting anywhere.

Comment: Is the number always at the end of the string? Try `string.match(a, '%d[%d,.]*')` or `string.match(a, '%S+$')`. Or  is the number always come after `totalling` word? Try `string.match(a, 'totalling%s*(%d[,.%d]*)')`. See see https://ideone.com/lSryCS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may extract the number in various ways:

```
local a = "totalling  7,525.07" -- 7,525.07
print(string.match(a, '%S+$'))  -- 7,525.07
print(string.match(a, '%d[%d.,]*'))   -- 7,525.07
print(string.match(a, 'totalling%s*(%S+)'))  -- 7,525.07
print(string.match(a, 'totalling%s*(%d[,.%d]*)'))  -- 7,525.07
print(string.match(a, '%f[%d]%d[,.%d]*%f[%D]'))  -- 7,525.07
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/lSryCS)

**Details**

- `%S+$`  - matches 1+ non-whitespace chars at the end of the string (as the number is at the end of the string, it works)
- `%d[%d.,]*` - a digit followed with 0+ digits, `.` or `,` chars
- `totalling%s*(%S+)` - matches `totalling`, 0+ whitespaces and then captures 0+ non-whitespace chars and returns the captured value
- `totalling%s*(%d[,.%d]*)` - also a pattern that relies on the `totalling` context, but using the second pattern to capture the number
- `%f[%d]%d[,.%d]*%f[%D]` - `%f[%d]` asserts the position between a non-digit and a digit, `%d[,.%d]*` matches a digit and then 0+ digits, `.` or `,` and `%f[%D]` fontier pattern asserts the position between a digit and a non-digit.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  How would I go about removing the comma but leaving the decimal?

Comment: @greenage: Add a `gsub`: [`string.match(a, '%f[%d]%d[,.%d]*%f[%D]'):gsub(",", "")`](https://ideone.com/GGF8An)

Answer (score 3):

just posting this because I think people will need something like this...

```
function getnumbersfromtext(txt)
local str = ""
string.gsub(txt,"%d+",function(e)
 str = str .. e
end)
return str;
end
-- example: 
-- getnumbersfromtext("Y&S9^%75r76gu43red67tgy")
-- it will output 975764367
```

hope this helps anyone who needs it :)